# Newcomer error in parsing tweet json UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 13-63: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to follow the Intro to Data Sci coursera class. But I have run into a problem while trying to parse json response from twitter

I am trying to retreive the text from the json that is in the following format.

```
{u'delete': {u'status': {u'user_id_str': u'702327198', u'user_id': 702327198, u'id': 332772178690981889L, u'id_str': u'332772178690981889'}}}, {u'delete': {u'status': {u'user_id_str': u'864736118', u'user_id': 864736118, u'id': 332770710667792384L, u'id_str': u'332770710667792384'}}}, {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, **u'text'**: u'RT @afgansyah_reza: Lagi ngantri. Ada ibu2 &amp; temennya. "Ih dia mukanya mirip banget sama Afgan.", trus ngedeketin gw, "Tuh kan.. Mirip bang\u2026', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 332772350640668672L, u'favorite_count': 0, ....... ]
```

And here is the code I am using for it:

```
def hw():
    data = []
    count=0
    with open('output.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            encoded_string = line.strip().encode('utf-8')
            data.append(json.loads(encoded_string))

    print data# generates the input to next block
    for listval in data:#individual block
        if "text" in listval:
            print listval["text"]
        else:
            continue
```

However I get the following output and  error when I run it

```
   RT @afgansyah_reza: Lagi ngantri. Ada ibu2 &amp; temennya. "Ih dia mukanya mirip banget sama Afgan.", trus ngedeketin gw, "Tuh kan.. Mirip bang…
RT @Dimaz_CSIX: Kolor pakek pita #laguharlemshake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\ProgrammingPoint\workspace-new\PyTest\tweet_sentiment.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\ProgrammingPoint\workspace-new\PyTest\tweet_sentiment.py", line 36, in main
    hw()
  File "F:\ProgrammingPoint\workspace-new\PyTest\tweet_sentiment.py", line 23, in hw
    print listval["text"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 13-63: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am a new comer to Python and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, one of the many advantages of learning Python 3.3 instead of 2.7 is that this stuff is a lot easier. (3.x forces you to deal with Unicode much earlier than 2.x does… but since you've already run into it with 2.x, that's not much of a downside.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of your conversion, etc. is correct. The problem is just trying to `print` it to stdout.

(Usually, you run into problems with accented, east-Asian, etc. characters; here it seems to be with the `…` ellipsis character, but it's the same problem.)

If you're running this in a terminal window (DOS prompt, etc.), you can only print characters that the terminal's character set can handle. So, for example, on a Windows box configured for 'cp1252' (like yours), you can't print non-Latin-1/non-Latin-15/non-ANSI characters.

(In earlier versions of Python, there's an additional problem that Python may not properly guess the best encoding for your terminal, and stick you with, say, `'ascii'` even though it can handle `utf-8`, or at least `cp1252`. You can find out what encoding Python has guessed for stdout with `sys.stdout.encoding`. If that's wrong, you can fix it explicitly.)

But if your terminal isn't UTF-8 (and it isn't), you need to tell it what to do with characters it can't represent. You can `encode` strings with an explicit `errors` parameter whenever you `print` them, like this:

```
print u.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace')
```

… or various other things. But if you want to fix this all in one place, you want to change the default error handler for printing.

Unfortunately, in Python 2.7, while `sys.stdout` does have an `errors` attribute, it's read-only. One way around this is to replace it with a wrapper around the original `sys.stdout` (or around its underlying file handle, or something else equivalent). For example:

```
>>> u = 'RT @afgansyah_reza: Lagi ngantri. Ada ibu2 &amp; temennya. "Ih dia mukanya mirip banget sama Afgan.", trus ngedeketin gw, "Tuh kan.. Mirip bang\xe2\x80\xa6'.decode('utf8')
>>> print u
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 13-63: character maps to <undefined>
>>> sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(sys.stdout.encoding)(sys.stdout, errors='replace')
>>> print u
RT @afgansyah_reza: Lagi ngantri. Ada ibu2 &amp; temennya. "Ih dia mukanya mirip banget sama Afgan.", trus ngedeketin gw, "Tuh kan.. Mirip bang?
```

For more information, read the [2.x Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), and the documentation on [`print`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement). They expect you to know that a `unicode` object is a string, so it does not get converted by `print`, but instead passed to `write` as-is. So, the trick is to put some kind of wrapper in `sys.stdout.write` that will write `str` objects as-is, but encode `unicode` objects differently. Either `codecs` or `io` can do this for you, but `codecs` is more backward-compatible (and `io` is more forward-compatible, but that doesn't make much difference here, because 3.x handles Unicode very differently).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I tried to append `sys.stdout.errors='replace'` to my code I got the following error `    sys.stdout.errors="replace"`
TypeError: readonly attribute`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oops, that _did_ used to be readonly. I thought that was changed in 2.7.0, but… I guess not. Let me update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PyDev Eclipse Plugin try going to Windows->Preferences->General->Workspace and choose at the left lower corner at TEXT FILE ENCODING -> Choose Other = UTF-8

It might work.

Answer (score 0):

Your json.loads call is converting the UTF-8 encoded json back into a Python Unicode string.  When you print it, it attempts to convert the text into your environment's default encoding, which the cp1252.py reference makes clear is Windows code page 1252.  You'll have to decide what output format and encode to that before printing.  If you want cp1252, give it an error handler other than the default of 'strict'.

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html has the full docs, including the various error handler possibilities.